# Default date as today date

Tags: date

I changed

```
<field name="n_date" default="0000-00-00" class="inputbox" format="%Y-%m-%d" translateformat="false" showtime="false" singleheader="false" todaybutton="false" weeknumbers="false" filltable="false" type="calendar" label="Date" description="COM_LATESTNEWS_FORM_DESC_DETAIL_N_DATE" hint="COM_LATESTNEWS_FORM_LBL_DETAIL_N_DATE"/>
```

to

```
<field name="n_date" default="" type="calendar" class="inputbox" filter="safehtml" label="COM_LATESTNEWS_FORM_LBL_DETAIL_N_DATE" description="COM_LATESTNEWS_FORM_DESC_DETAIL_N_DATE" hint="COM_LATESTNEWS_FORM_LBL_DETAIL_N_DATE" required="true"/>
```

Reason of changing - date was incorrect showing in previous version of jan 2022
Now after changing whats happening is that n_date field coming as blank and has to manually select today date on clicking.

Is there a way by which default date should be picked and showed as today date when not selected by default

Answer (score 1):

To show the current date or timedate as the default, you can simply use `default="now"`.

Note, that you will also need to set `translateformat="true"`

You can read more about the Joomla Calendar Field [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Calendar_form_field_type)

Comment: Thanks, what if translateformat is not added. any harm ?

Comment: I got PHP error, which is probably because the format of the `default` date needs to be able to be read within the actual calendar.